# php timezone setting mandatory

Tags: timezone, php

At first my default timezone setting (I uncommented it after) in my php.ini file was commented and I did not declare my timezone in any of my scripts. I received an error that said that a declaration of the timezone is required and that it is not safe to rely on the system's timezone. Why is the timezone required if I am not using any functions in my scripts that are related to timezones, dates, etc?What is its use in this situation.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is of course only used for dates. But note that it is used for all dates, including if you are writing a date in a log file, etc. Using dates in some form is quite common. Also it's probably easier to put that check in the startup, so it's checked once, and not every time you use a date function.